# Windows server 2012 R2 IIS Hosting application

Tags: windows, web-services, iis, tcp

Hello i am trying to host a site on my windows server 2012 R2 and trying to access from my static public ip address but it not happening not sure where am going wrong my steps to do it was.

1. Add Website from applications Pools -> Site Name(test.com)
2. Physical path (C:\test.com)
3. Ip address as my local static ip (192.168.1.6) Port (93)
4. Then Click OK
5. add inbound rule in windows firewall -> port ->93 TCP ->Allow All connections -> Domain private and public -> description done
6. added port forward tcp for ip address 192.168.1.6 port 93

7.browsing from public ip address: WITH PORT not working

Please let me know where am going wrong am new to this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You did mistake on step #3, in your bindings you need to use your public static IP. So, your steps should be like that:

1. Add Website from applications Pools -> Site Name(test.com)
2. Physical path (C:\test.com)
3. Ip address of your public static IP (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) Port (93) or you can select 'All Unassigned' option
4. Then Click OK
5. add inbound rule in windows firewall -> port ->93 TCP ->Allow All connections -> Domain private and public -> description done
6. added port forward tcp for ip address 192.168.1.6 port 93 (in your router)
7. browsing from public ip address: WITH PORT not working

If it is still not working, you need to check if port is actually open and nothing is blocking your port.

1. [Install telnet client](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-install-use-telnet-client-windows-7-windows-81)
2. Execute on command prompt this command `telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 93` where XXX is your public IP. Telnet should successfully create connection to this port

Comment: I am sorry to say i made the changes i added public IP address in to my ipv 4 advance setting and selected in IP section still not working

Comment: Telnet is pinging the IP address with port

Comment: Are you sure that port forwarding is working in your router?

Comment: Hmm :( is it i have added port forwarding with TCP for port 93

Comment: Can you test again for me ?

Comment: cant i use port 80 indeed its open ma be isp is blocking my ports